# Is this schema design approach correct?

Tags: mysql, plaxo

The next question is about an assignment for school:

I have to make a web application like [plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com/), where there are users and each one of them has it's own agenda. The requirements of my application are much simpler than plaxo's. Mine would only have contacts grouped by category and tasks grouped by their state in completed or pending, and other typical functionalities.

My doubt is with the sql schema. This would be the model i would choose:

- users(id, username, password, name, lastname, email)
- categories(id,name)
- contacts(id, name, adress, phone, email, **id_categories**, **id_users**)
- contacts_person(id, lastname, **id_contact**)
- contacts_organization(id, trademark, **id_contact**)
- tasks(id, date, hour, description)
- tasks_contacts(**id_tasks**, **id_contacts**)

The fields that are on bold are foreign keys.
I'm not sure if this schema is allright, i don't think so. **Please let me know if it's not**,

**______________________________________________________________________**

**EDIT** after @Strawberry comment:

Ok, lets say i changed the model to this one:

- categories(id,name)
- contacts(id, name, email)
- contacts_user(username, password, **id_contacts**)
- contacts_person(lastname, adress, phone, **id_contacts**)
- contacts_organization(trademark, adress, phone, **id_contacts**)
- tasks(id, date, hour, description)
- tasks_contacts(**id_tasks**, **id_contacts**)

Took out the **id** field from contacts_user, contacts_person and contacts_organization because i believe it's nonsense considering that **id_contacts** would be an unique key.

I will add some more information:

- Table users is for the data that a user stores when it registers.
- Categories are meant to group contacts. Ex: John, Luis and Anna can be in the category "family", because they are familiars.
- Each contact can only be part of one category.
- There are two types of contacts, organizations and persons. The difference between them is that persons don't have trademarks and organizations don't have lastnames.
- Each task has to have a reminder date and hour. I don't know if task
  is the best traduccion to english from the spanish "recordatorio",
  but plaxo seems to call it that way.
- Each contact can have more than one task or reminder associated and each task can have more than one contact associated.

Hope i made myself clear enough.

Comment: Tryed to avoid that. Where?
It results difficult for me to apply normalization concepts.

Comment: Thaks for your help @Strawberry. I've updated the question considering what you wrote.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I should have considered listing some requirements, next time i will

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103365/discussion-between-hernan-and-strawberry).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change the first model in order to reduce redundancy:

*data tables*

- users(id, username, password, name, lastname, email)
- contacts(id, name, lastname, adress, phone, email)
- organizations(id, trademark)
- tasks(id, date, hour, description)
- categories(id,name)

*relations*

- users_categories(**id_categories**, **id_users**)
- contacts_categories(**id_categories**, **id_contact**)
- user_contacts(**user_id**,  **id_contact**)
- organization_contacts(**organization_id**, **id_contact**)
- tasks_contacts(**id_tasks**, **id_contacts**)
- ...

Bottomline: store all data of one entity in one table and have the relations between entities in tables which only holds foreign keys but no additional data.

Adding columns to one of the entities then doesn't interfere with the relations.

Adding more relations doesn't need to know about the data structure of related entities.

Comment: Date,hour? Not sure about that one!

Comment: @Strawberry Its the _definition_ of a task. This has a date and probably an hour, that's application specific which isn't requested here, I think. One may combine that in to a `timestamp` and a `duration` which might be mre appropriate, but as I said, application stuff.